# How to Sort a Query by a Column Containing Numbers as Text

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following problem where I'm querying from one tab to another, and then trying to sort one of the columns by rating (AA), and days past (X, which is a negative number since it represents the amount of days past a deadline). The querying looks as follows:

```
  =QUERY('(Name of Tab1)'!K7:AA,"SELECT K, N , X, Z, AA WHERE X != 'Closed' ORDER BY X ASC")
```

The issue is that I'm getting sorts for Column X that look like this:

```
-279.00
-3.00
-10.00
-106.00
-11.00
-12.00
-12.00
-13.00
-14.00
-144.00
-149.00
```

Clearly, this isn't the sort I want and it's pretty evident that it's reading it as a string and not an int. However, whenever I try to use SQL functions like cast as int, it doesn't work. 
How can I convert these values into an int so then it sorts everything properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm baffled.  Your query returns four columns but you are only showing 1.  Your query orders by two columns, and the one you specify is not the first key.

Comment: The first column order does not matter, I remove it and get exactly the same issue. The problem is purely with this column alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to sort a query by a column containing numbers as text

The issue you face has nothing to do with the *"numbers"* being negative.
It is because the column/cells containing the numbers are formatted as text.
**Text cells cannot be sorted**.

Please use the following formula:

```
=QUERY({'Name of Tab1'!K7:W44,ARRAYFORMULA('Name of Tab1'!X7:X44*1),'Name of Tab1'!Y7:AA44}, 
       "SELECT Col1, Col4, Col14 , Col16, Col17 WHERE Col14 is not null and Col1<>'' ORDER BY Col14")
```

[image: How to sort a query by a column containing numbers as text]

---

### How the formula works:

1. We split our range into 3 parts

   - The part before our *"numbers"* column `'Name of Tab1'!K7:W44`
   - Our "numbers" column `ARRAYFORMULA('Name of Tab1'!X7:X44*1)`
   - The last part `'Name of Tab1'!Y7:AA44`
2. Because we now have our 3 ranges in curly brackets `{}` we cannot use column letters. Instead, we must use `Col1`, `Col4` etc, where **`Col1` is the 1st column in our combined range**, `Col4` is our previous `X` column and so on.
3. About our *"numbers"* column `ARRAYFORMULA('Name of Tab1'!X7:X44*1)`.
   An **Arrayformula multiplied by 1 turns every text cell containing numbers to be formatted as number** and the ones with text *(in our case `Closed`)* result to `#VALUE!` which get skipped using `WHERE Col14 is not null` *(instead of our original `WHERE X != 'Closed'`)*

---

Functions used:

- **[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)**
- **[ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)**

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked beautifully. Just for some further conceptual knowledge, why does adding 3 ranges in curly brackets mean that we now have to reference columns by Col1, Col2, etc instead of their respective letters?

Comment: This is just the way the `QUERY` function works. It is a great feature because by using curly brackets the order of the columns is relevant to the query itself. The formula becomes _"column-independent"_ . Try `=QUERY(A1:C3, "where B is not null")` vs `=QUERY({A1:C3}, "where Col2 is not null")`. Thank you for taking the time to accept.

Comment: *Just a thought*. You could probably edit and add "How to sort a query by a column containing numbers as text" in the top of your question, since this is actually what the issue was. I think it would help others find the answer easier. If you don't have the time I could try that for you and you can accept or reject my edit.

Comment: I agree, will do!